# Laravel validates field that DOESN'T EXIST in my database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am working on a project, at first everything worked perfectly until I changed my database fields and removed one attribute.
Now the registration keeps showing this error "**The type field is required**"
I checked all my files in case there was a required field called type but there isn't any.
Here are my files :
RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);

    // The blog post is valid...
}

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
        $role = Role::select('id')->where('name', 'Utilisateur')->first();

        $user->roles()->attach($role);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

register.blade.php

```
@if (count($errors->getBags()))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->getBags() as $bag)
                @foreach ($bag->getMessages() as $messages)
                    @foreach ($messages as $message)
                        <li>{{ $message }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

<?php use App\Models\Role;?>
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf



                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nome et prénom') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                      


                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Address E-Mail ') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Mot de passe') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirmer mot de passe') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

users table

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
            $table->text('profile_photo_path')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('approved')->default(0)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        });
    }
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role');

    }

    public function hasAnyRoles($roles)
    {
        if($this->roles()->whereIn('name' , $roles)->first()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if($this->roles()->where('name' , $role)->first()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function assignRole(Role $role)
    {
        return $this->roles()->save($role);
    }

}
```

I am so hopeless right now, I tried absolutely everything I could think of, read every possible related issue but i couldn't solve mine.
Any help is much appreciated as I'm fairly new to Laravel and my project is due tomorrow !
Thank you

Comment: Clear your caches; based on the code here there's no problem.

Comment: I cleared all caches using the php artisan optimize:clear command but the error still shows

Comment: have you tried to remove `bootstrap/cache/` and `storage/framework/views` files??

Comment: Make sure your route is pointing to the correct controller method also.

Comment: You don't show the `Role` model. Could the issue be in that model or table?

Comment: thank you ! I am not sure how I ended up solving the issue, but now the registration form works perfectly.